# Adding a dot to the name of each paragraph in KOMA-Script

Tags: formatting, koma-script, paragraphs

I am currently (trying) to make KOMA-Script put a dot after the name of each paragraph. Meaning, if I write `\paragraph{Test} Lorem Ipsum`, then this should result in LaTeX typesetting it as `Test. Lorem Ipsum`, but of course with the correct font and everything for `Test`.

Reading the KOMA-Script guide, I found that I should be able to get this result by redefining `\paragraphformat` (see [on the top of page 110 in the KOMA-Script Documentation](https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)). However, KOMA-Script seems to right out ignore me redefining `\paragraphformat`.

I reproduced the problem in the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\paragraphformat}{\theparagraph.\enskip}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Test} Lorem Ipsum

\end{document}
```

I then get the following result (where I would expect a dot after **Test**):
[image: MWE result]

Also, I tried to replace the dot with undefined commands but nothing happens. I thus guess that LaTeX is completely ignoring me redefining this command.

**EDIT:** As campa nicely pointed out in the comments, the `\paragraphformat` only defines the format of the numbering. As paragraphs (at least in my MWE) are not numbered, the redefinition correctly had no effect. It seems that `\DeclareSectionCommand` and related commands are meant to be used for what I am trying to do. However, while there are many options to configure, adding a dot in the end of each paragraph name does not seem to be one of them. Since I don't have too much time at my hands at the moment, I went with the following hacky solution of redefining the `paragraph` command:

```latex
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1.}}
```

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding what the `\...format` do: it's about the *numbering*. The class isn't ignoring your code, but since paragraphs are not normally numbered you see nothing in the output. Try adding `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` to your code to see what I mean. You should better rephrase your question in something like "how do I add stuff after the paragraph title" or similar.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you! I'll look into the guide again, probably there is some section about this, and if the question then doesn't resolve itself will adapt it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```latex
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/paragraph}{\headingdot}
\newcommand*{\headingdot}[1]{.}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/paragraph}{\headingdot}
\newcommand*{\headingdot}[1]{.}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Test} Lorem Ipsum
\subparagraph{Foo} Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can redefine `\sectioncatchphraseformat`:

```latex
\renewcommand*\sectioncatchphraseformat[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3#4\Ifstr{#1}{paragraph}{.}{}%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand*\sectioncatchphraseformat[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3#4\Ifstr{#1}{paragraph}{.}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Test} Lorem Ipsum
\subparagraph{Foo} Text
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: I really like the `\AddtoDoHook` solution. It seems to be the cleanest solution so far. Thank you for proposing it :-)