# KOMA-Script: how to set indentation of a runin section to \parindent?

Tags: koma-script

I would like to set a normal paragraph indent for a `runin` section title in KOMA-Script. Strangely, the latter ignores `indent = \parindent` in `RedeclareSectionCommand`. `\the\parindent` sets the indent, but to a wrong value.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, paper = 140mm : 216mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    style     = section
  , runin     = true
  , font      = \normalfont\bfseries
  , afterskip = \the\fontdimen2\font
  , indent    = \parindent
]{section}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section.}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{
    \setlength{\parindent}{%
        \dimexpr2\baselineskip-1ex\relax}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Bananas are great}
\section{About bananas.}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

How can I specify the indent to be `\parindent` (I am not typesetting English text, so let's omit why)?

Oh, I also would love to specify `\fontdimen2\font` for `afterskip`, but it doesn't work as well, and who knows for what font `\the` sets the `afterskip` to.

Finally, is there a way to not manually add a dot after the section title? Like `\section{About bananas}` instead of `\section{About bananas.}`?

[image]

Comment: `indent    = \the\parindent`  seems to work. (but it will take the value of \parindent at definition time, not your setting in begin document).

Comment: To get an automatic dot after the section title, follow either of the solutions in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604521/
You'll just need to substitute "section" for "paragraph" there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yep, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my full solution. Thanks to @marquinho for a tip.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, paper = 140mm : 216mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\newcommand*\ssize{\fontdimen2\font}
\newcommand*\wspace{\nolinebreak\hspace{\ssize}\relax}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection.\wspace}
\newcommand*{\headingdot}[1]{.}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{\headingdot}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \setlength{\parindent}{%
        \dimexpr2\baselineskip-1ex\relax}
    \RedeclareSectionCommand[
        style     = section
      , runin     = true
      , font      = \normalfont\bfseries
      , afterskip = \the\ssize
      , indent    = \the\parindent
      ]{section}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Mind reading introduction}
\section{Telepathy fundamentals}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the parameters at begin document, not in the preamble, so after `\normalfont` has been issued. If you want to indent section titles, you also need `indentfirst`.

Rather than hardwiring the period in `\thesection` (because you probably don't want it in cross-references, do you?) it's better to use `scrbook` features.

For the `afterskip` I defined it with stretch and shrink components, so it participates to justification.

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  twoside,
  paper = 140mm : 216mm,
  numbers = endperiod,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\newlength{\sectionparindent}
\newlength{\sectionafterskip}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style     = section,
  runin     = true,
  font      = \normalfont\bfseries,
  afterskip = \sectionafterskip,
  indent    = \sectionparindent,
]{section}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{\dimexpr2\baselineskip-1ex\relax}%
  \setlength{\sectionparindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\sectionafterskip}{\fontdimen2\font plus \fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Bananas are great}

Let's see what the parindent is.

\section{About bananas.}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]